# Listing alternatives in a question

Tags: questions, punctuation

What punctuation should I use in a question that offers alternatives?

> What do you like, cheese or bacon?

> What do you like? Cheese or bacon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do you like, cheese or bacon?

This is the grammatically correct way of saying this.

> What do you like? Cheese or bacon?

This is more informal and colloquial.

Alternatively, if you were listing items, you could use a colon.

> Which do you like: cheese, bacon, or cheesy bacon?

Note, you do not capitalize after the colon.

Answer (score 1):

Informally, I think both are OK. But in a strict sense

> What do you like, cheese or bacon?

seems better to me. "Cheese or bacon?" by itself is not a complete sentence.
Also, *which* might be better than *what*, as a limited choice is implied.

To make this simpler, you might say

> Do you like cheese or bacon?

which has the same meaning.